# Calculating mutual events with continuous distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Suppose $\ X \sim U(-4,7) $

Compute: $\ P\{X^2 - 16 > 0 \ | \ X > 0 \} $

My attempt:

$$\ P\{ X^2 - 16 > 0 | X>0 \} = P \{ X > 4 | X > 0 \} = \frac{P\{X>4\}}{P\{X>0\} } $$

I'm just not sure I understand what how to calculate the probability of $\ P\{ X > a \}  \cap P\{X > b\} $ with continues variables. Is it equal to $\ P\{X > a \} \cdot P\{X >b \} $

When I draw a uniform distribution it's seems like it is $\ P\{ X > a | X >b \} = \frac{P\{X>a\}}{P\{X>b\}} $ where $\ a > b $ but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First verify that $\{X^2-16 > 0\} = \{X > 4\} \cup \{X < -4\}$.

Then by definition of conditional probability we have \begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\big(\{X^2 - 16 > 0\} \mid \{X>0\}\big) &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(\{X^2-16 > 0\} \cap \{X>0\})}{\mathbb{P}(X>0)} \\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}\big(\left(\{X > 4\} \cup \{X < -4\}\big) \cap \{X>0\}\right)}{\mathbb{P}(X>0)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}\big(\left(\{X > 4\} \cap \{X > 0\}\right) \cup \left(\{X <- 4\} \cap \{X > 0\}\right)\big)}{\mathbb{P}(X>0)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}\big(\{X > 4\}\cup \emptyset\big)}{\mathbb{P}(X>0)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X > 4)}{\mathbb{P}(X>0)}\\
&= \frac37
\end{align}

Comment: Yes, thanks well I forget to add that I understand that if $\ X> 0 $ then $\ X > -4 $ . So the conditional probability in that case is 1. And Just needed to check the case of $\ X > 4 $.

Comment: @bm1125 Careful, $X^2 -16 > 0$ is equivalent to $X > 0$ or $X < -4$. Not $X > -4$ as you say.

Comment: That's important note! Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Well what is the intersection of the sets? What does it mean if $\omega$ is fulfilling $X(\omega) > a$ and $X(\omega) > b$?

Comment: Well from what I see if $\ a >b $ then the intersection of the sets is  $\  P\{X > b \} $ . Am I correct?

Comment: No, if $a >b$ we have $\lbrace X>a \rbrace \subseteq \lbrace X>b \rbrace$.